# Next Row ID appears before values are entered

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to get my sheet to auto-generate an ID on google sheets, which works on the first row but the next ID would be generated before i enter any values.

```
function myFunction() {



 var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sequence Tbl");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        // Here the columns & rows are 1-indexed
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setNumberFormat("00000");
      }
    } catch(ex) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output? You are setting value up to the next row of last row with `row+1`.

Comment: desired output is to have the id column (A) to auto gen the ID starting from 1-9999 , when column B is filled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vals = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, 2);
```